# TypeCasting an Xpp3Dom object

Tags: java, maven, dom, casting

I have the following requirement. I am reading the POM file of an artifact and saving the configuration for a certain plugin in an Xpp3Dom object. 
I have an external Library that works with parsing this configuration, for this I need to cast this Xpp3Dom object into a type that this library can parse.

How is this possible? Since Xpp3dom is an unrelated class. I can use a superType which is Object but this gives me runtime ClassCast exceptions

```
Xpp3Dom myObject = initialize ;
CustomObject customObj =  (CustomObject) (Object) myObject;
```

any idea on how to go about this?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a plugin? Can you give more details about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The customObject is in the plugin that corresponds to the DOM object

Comment: Sorry but that does not help... I know that this is the plexus configuration. But why do you need to access them directly parmeters are injects automatically during runtime....?Best would be to show a real example what you have so far and explain based on the example what the problem is...